# Build Vue+Vuetify use 'npm start build'

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use Vue and Vuetify library in one project.

I went to https://vuetifyjs.com and followed the instructions to create a project with vue-cli:

**vue init vuetifyjs/webpack my-proto**

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

Open browser type localhost:8080 everything works and looks awesome.

I didn't change any code and ran the command:

```
npm start build
```

Which output the following:

> **94% asset optimization**
>
> **ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors**
>
> **This dependency was not found: /Users/.../Projects/my-proto/build/ in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client? http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server ./build/**
>
> **To install it, you can run: npm install --save /Users/.../my-proto/build/**

I really don't understand anything, because this is original code which was previously building without any errors.

What kind of dependency are we talking about if all code works fine in a browser?

```
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: It seems like you're missing the `build` folder

Comment: I have 'Build' folder in project. I didn't create it. This is part of vue-cli build routine.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake.
I run command: **npm start build**, but I have to  use another command: **npm run build** So Issue closed